# Pandas timeseries , filter for second to last businessday

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter out all the rows of data that are the second to last business day per month in my Dataframe.
the date is in the form of :

```
1993-02-04
```

Comment: Please, add [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please post a sample dataframe and a desired output.  It might be helpful to review [ask], as well as create a [mcve]

Comment: I am voting to close this question because it does not fully address the question, and doesn't provide input and desired output

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by calculating the second to last business day of the month and then using a boolean mask to filter. I am assuming your dataframe contains the dates in the `datetime` format in the `'date'` column.

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay, MonthEnd

second_to_last_bday_of_current_month = df['date'] + MonthEnd() - 2 * BDay()

excluded = df[df['date'] != second_to_last_bday_of_current_month]
```